# Android googledocs app component name

Tags: android-layout

I am planning to provide menus for my app similar to the sliding menu shown in the below image when clicking on the button in the list view. Could you give me some pointers on, how it can be achieved. Is it SubMenu ?

http://static5.businessinsider.com/image/4db84baeccd1d58435080000/google-docs-for-android.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, the behavior or pattern name is QuikActions.
Useful introductory article for the beginners like me is available in the following link
http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/